# Codeigniter first time user

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I need a way to tell if it's a user's first time to log in--so I can display relevant information to that user about what they need to do.

How can this be achieved?  I'm at a loss here and examples would be appreciated!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often useful to store the 'last login' time and date for users. If you did that you could simply check if `last_login` was NULL in your users table and then display your message or whatever.

Comment: A last_login timestamp is generally more useful than a simple first_login flag, and is no more difficult to implement.

Comment: Thanks, again!  Your answer was helpful to a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

this isn't really a codeigniter specific question.  You would want to interact with a database that stores user information.  A "user" table could have a field in it that gets set to "true" (or some value) when a user logs in for the first time (which you could subsequently query).  Codeigniter does make it easier for you to interact with a database - just do a search (or look in their excellent documentation) for Codeigniter *ActiveRecord*.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store something like that in the database:

```
username varchar 255
password varchar 255
first_login bool default 1
```

If first_login is 1, display the information and set first_login to 0

Answer (score 0):

You can store one field in the database, like `flagFirstLogin = 1` uppon the registration and after the first login you just change that to 0.